# Asymptotics for the sequence A094589

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, closed-form

Consider the integer sequence

$$1,2,4,6,10,14,20,26,32,38,48,...$$

Defined here

http://oeis.org/A094589

Im looking for good asymptotics.
And proofs of them.

I considered $\frac{n(n-\sqrt n)}{2}$ but that appears not So good. Not even sure If it is a main term ?

Any asymptotic ( in closed form ) that is better is helpful.

---

I assume there is a fast way to compute values of this sequence with large index, without requiring most of the previous values. Just a feeling.

Comment: Your idea is good. For $n=1024$, your formula leads to $507904$ while the exact value is $509790$

Comment: Thank you but I need better. And Some formal explainations.

Comment: $n(n-\sqrt{n})/2 + n$ seems to do slightly better, up to $n=5000$.

Comment: @Olivier. It could be something between.

Comment: My bet is that for all $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$, eventually $\frac{n(n-\sqrt{n})}{2}+ \delta n \le a(n) \le \frac{n(n-\sqrt{n})}{2} + n^{\varepsilon}$. This is just from exploring with mathematica; nothing serious.  :^)

Comment: That makes No sense. Typo ?

Comment: Why does that make no sense? Maybe there's a typo I can't see, but it was otherwise verified numerically. I should emphasize the *eventually*: the inequalities are meant to hold only for large $n$.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the sequence $a_n$ will have any nice asymptotic formula.

By studying the values of $a_n$ for $n$ upto $10^6$, $a_n$ seems to
contain some non-trivial oscillation with slowing increasing period. It is sort of
hard to describe what it is without a picture. We will back to this later.

Using some hand-waving argument, I have approximated the original difference equation by an ODE:

$$a_{n+1} - a_n = a\left(\lfloor a^{-1}(n) \rfloor\right)
\quad\leadsto\quad
a'(n) = n - \frac13 - \frac12 a'(a^{-1}(n))
$$

To first and second order, this lead to following two approximations of $a_n$:

$$
a^{[1]}_n = \frac{n}{2}\left(n -\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{n}\right)
\quad\text{ AND }\quad
a^{[2]}_n = n\left(\frac{n}{2}-\frac23\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac12} +\frac{2}{15}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac14} - \frac16\right)
$$
To compare them with the approximation proposed in question,

$$a^{[0]}_n = \frac{n}{2}\left(n - \sqrt{n}\right)$$

I have plotted their errors in a single picture:

[image: Errors in different approximations]

In above picture,

- the red curve is $\frac{1}{10n}(a_n - a^{[0]}_n)$,
- the green curve is $\frac{1}{n}(a_n - a^{[1]}_n)$,
- the blue curve is $\frac{1}{n}(a_n - a^{[2]}_n)$,

There are two observations one can make:

1. The red curve and green curve has approximately the same size. Since the red curve represent errors of original approximation scaled down by a factor of ten, approximation $a^{[1]}_n$ is about an order of magnitude better than $a^{[0]}_n$
2. Unlike the red and green curves which drift away from $0$, 
   the leading behavior of the blue curve is some cusp like oscillation, the amplitude doesn't seem to die down as $n$ increases and the period of seems to grow very slowly.
   What this means is if one want to go beyond approximation $a^{[2]}_n$,
   one need to include corrections other than powers of $n$. 
   A classical asymptotic expansion purely in terms of powers of $n$ and $\log(n)$ won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I used a CAS to find a fit similar to your formula and this one works great

$p(n)=\left\lceil 0.5 n^2-\dfrac{n\sqrt n}{3}\right\rceil$

Look at this table

$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
n & \textit{actual value} & p(n)\\
\hline
 1000 & 485930 & 489460 \\
 2000 & 1959566 & 1970186 \\
 3000 & 4424886 & 4445228 \\
 4000 & 7885142 & 7915673 \\
 5000 & 12339310 & 12382149 \\
 6000 & 17787118 & 17845081 \\
 7000 & 24231714 & 24304780 \\
 8000 & 31672274 & 31761487 \\
 9000 & 40107314 & 40215396 \\
 10000 & 49540314 & 49666667 \\
\end{array}
$$

***Edit***

I remade fitting computation considering not sequential data but, just to say, every $500$ and I got a much better approximating function

$p_2(n)=\left\lceil 0.497 n^2-17.183 n\right\rceil$

Look at the new table

$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
n & \textit{actual value} & p_2(n)\\
\hline
 1000 & 485930 & 479817 \\
 2000 & 1959566 & 1953634 \\
 3000 & 4424886 & 4421451 \\
 4000 & 7885142 & 7883268 \\
 5000 & 12339310 & 12339085 \\
 6000 & 17787118 & 17788902 \\
 7000 & 24231714 & 24232719 \\
 8000 & 31672274 & 31670536 \\
 9000 & 40107314 & 40102353 \\
 10000 & 49540314 & 49528170 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: This formula does worst than $n(n-\sqrt n)/2 +n$, at least up to $n=10000$. Try incorporating a linear term into the model too?

Comment: For your edit: $n(n-\sqrt n)/2 + 3n$ does better when $n=1000, 10000,  12000$, while your formula does better somewhere in between.

Comment: @Olivier I have improved the formula $p_3(n)=\left\lceil 0.498 n^2-24.946 n\right\rceil$ but I think that yours is more natural.